# Get directory of a matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a matrix saved in another folder. and I want to ask the user to chose the matrix then I get its directory and load it.

For loading, I know I have to use scipy.io.loadmat. However, to ask the user for the directory, I'm not sure if I have to use Tkinter or something else.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your end product look like? If it's a GUI-like application, then probably go with Tkinter, but if you are just testing out or it's a script-like function, then you can just use `input` to get user input.

Comment: I'm thinking about a GUI-like apllication. a Window pops up a allow the user to chose the matrix. Then, I get the excat directory.

Answer (score 0):

I find a way 
Just in case someone has the same question, you find in the following the script that i used

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
MatrixPath = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("HDF5", "*.h5"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
Matrix = h5py.File(MatrixPath, 'r')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filedialog` from `tkinter` [tkinter with examples](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/tkfilebrowser/stable/tkfilebrowser.pdf)

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import filedialog
except:
    print('Tkinter for python3 not installed. Run the following command to set it up:')
    print('For Windows : pip3 install python3-tk ')
    print('For Linux : sudo apt-get install python3-tk')
    sys.exit(1)

def GetMatrix():
    path = tk.Tk()
    mat_dir = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Select the mat file') # Navigate to the folder and select the file
    path.withdraw()
    return mat_dir

# Use the function in the main code
```